# DRF solving nested serializers circular import dependency

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

So, Here is my serializers structure in the Django Rest FrameWork:

```py
class FieldDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = FieldData
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_kwargs = {'data_size': {'read_only': True}, }

    parent = DataSheetFieldSerializer(many=False, required=True)
    owner = MemberSerializer(many=False, required=True)


class IndexedFieldDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = IndexedFieldData
        fields = '__all__'

    field_data = FieldDataSerializer(many=False, required=True)


class DataSheetFieldSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DataSheetField
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_kwargs = {'is_indexed': {'read_only': True}, }

    @property
    def field_size(self):
        return record_data_manager.get_field_size(self.data['id'])

    size = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='field_size')
    data = FieldDataSerializer(many=True)
    indexed_data = IndexedFieldDataSerializer(many=True)
    owner = MemberSerializer(many=False, required=True)
    parent = DataSheetSerializer(many=False, required=True)


class DataSheetsCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DataSheetsCategory
        fields = '__all__'

    parent = ClusterSerializer(many=False, required=True)


class DataSheetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DataSheet
        fields = '__all__'

    @property
    def datasheet_size(self):
        return record_data_manager.get_datasheet_size(self.data['id'])

    size = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='datasheet_size')
    fields = DataSheetFieldSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    parent = DataSheetsCategorySerializer(required=False, many=False)
    owner = MemberSerializer(required=True, many=False)


class ClusterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DataSheetsCluster
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_kwargs = {'total_size_limit': {'read_only': True}, }

    @property
    def cluster_size(self):
        return record_data_manager.get_cluster_size(self.data['id'])

    size = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='cluster_size')
    members = MemberSerializer(many=True)
    roles = RoleSerializer(many=True)
    datasheets = DataSheetSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    owner = MemberSerializer(many=False, required=True)
```

As you can see, I am having trouble because of my model's structure.
I cannot reference the serializers below and hence am getting an unreferenced error, my serializers are nested. How can I solve this error? Can someone pls help me? thanks!

Comment: How are the models structured? Do they also have the nested issue?  Models and serializers usually have a close, if not identical, structure.

Comment: I used strings to mention the models, but the same cannot be done to the serializers. I know that there is the string serializer, but its read only. I dont want read only. Thanks!

Comment: Do the models work?

Comment: Yes, they work.

Comment: This is how I mentioned the models. Heres a sample: `parent = models.ForeignKey('api_backend.DataSheetField' , on_delete = models.CASCADE)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `SerializerMethodField` and it's get_FIELDNAME method should allow this.

```
class DataSheetFieldSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DataSheetField
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_kwargs = {'is_indexed': {'read_only': True}, }

    @property
    def field_size(self):
        return record_data_manager.get_field_size(self.data['id'])

    size = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='field_size')
    data = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    indexed_data = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    owner = MemberSerializer(many=False, required=True)
    parent = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_data(self, obj):
        return FieldDataSerializer(obj.data).data

    def get_indexed_data(self, obj):
        return IndexedFieldDataSerializer(obj.indexed_data).data

    def get_parent(self, obj):
        return DataSheetFieldSerializer(obj.parent).data
```

Comment: this is the best answer the internet has found so far regarding drf serializers circular imports. I was searching so long, couldn't find one.

Comment: Happy to hear it's useful. `SerializerMethodField()` and `to_representation()` are very helpful DRF methods.

Comment: This is read only. Write operations are not supported vis method field.